# Trying to convert string to MarketDataIncrementalRefresh

Tags: c#, quickfix, fix-protocol

I have a text file with `FIX messages` (all of them and MarketDataIncrementalRefresh (Type X)) and I'm trying to find a way using `QuickFIX` in `C#` to create `MarketDataIncrementalRefresh` messages out of the `strings`.

Any suggestions?

here is an example of how one line looks like:

> 1128=9 9=263 35=X 49=CME 34=10568699 52=20110110205433535 75=20110110 268=2 279=1 22=8 48=812201 83=1243518 107=GEZ2 269=1 270=9825.0 271=153 273=205433000 336=2 346=14 1023=1 279=122=8 48=812201 83=1243519 107=GEZ2 269=1270=9826.0 271=453 273=205433000 336=2 346=21 1023=3 10=058

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically this is how its done:

```
string line = sr.ReadLine();
QuickFix42.MessageFactory fac = new QuickFix42.MessageFactory();
QuickFix.MsgType msgType = QuickFix.Message.identifyType(line);
QuickFix.Message message = fac.create("", msgType.getObject() as string);
message.setString(line, false);
```

The factory creates the proper message type once its given, so in this case since the type was {X}, QuickFix.Message message is a pointer to MarketDataIncrementalRefresh and then message.setString sets the rest of the props from the given string.

Answer (score 1):

in Java you can use either

`MessageUtils.parse(MessageFactory messageFactory, DataDictionary dataDictionary, java.lang.String messageString)`

[see here.](http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/javadoc/1.5.1/quickfix/MessageUtils.html)

of the Message object itself, [see here](http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/javadoc/1.5.1/quickfix/Message.html#fromString%28java.lang.String,%20quickfix.DataDictionary,%20quickfix.DataDictionary,%20boolean%29) either using the constructor:

```
Message(java.lang.String string, DataDictionary dd, boolean validate)
```

or the fromString method:

```
fromString(java.lang.String messageData, DataDictionary sessionDictionary, DataDictionary applicationDictionary, boolean doValidation)
```

You should be able to find similar things for quickfix/n

I have only found [this](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/class_f_i_x_1_1_message.html), which only allows you to build a message from the string using the constructor.  Never the less this should work if you cannot find the equivalent of the above in your chosen API.

Comment: Thanks you I will look at quickfix/n. I know that the quickfix .net wrapper doesn't have MessageUtils.parse hopefully quickfix/n has it. As for the string ctor in FIX.message it does work but all it does is create message. I need it to create the proper message type in my case MarketDataIncrementalRefresh, to put it in other words can you find me a way to convert message to MarketDataIncrementalRefresh?

Comment: try MessageCracker http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/class_f_i_x_1_1_message_cracker.html, I am not sure how it works exactly in c# have a look at this example. http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/receiving-messages It is for a FIX application that receives message from a server.  However have your app also inherit MessageCracker, read the FIX string in to a Message as above, then call crack on the Message.  Override the relevant onMessage Method ie onMessage(MarketDataIncrementReferesh msg){} and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I want to perform the same conversion but I do not found `setString` in `QuickFix.Message`. I am using `QuickFIXn`. I searched more and check few more `methods` in `Message` and found a way. You can use `Message.FromString` method like below.

If you do not want to use `DataDictionary` then just pass it as `null`.

```
string strMsg = "8=FIX.4.49=54735=AE34=4";

var dataDictionary = new QuickFix.DataDictionary.DataDictionary();
dataDictionary.Load("../../../spec/fix/FIX44.xml");

var tradeCaptureReport = new QuickFix.FIX44.TradeCaptureReport();
tradeCaptureReport.FromString(strMsg, false, dataDictionary, dataDictionary, _defaultMsgFactory);
```